# Where are the keys for Elon Musk's (Starman's) Tesla Roadster?

Tags: tesla-roadster

In [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24365/can-i-drive-elon-musks-tesla-after-its-been-in-space-for-100-years) question, the OP posits that the keys will be in the ignition if/when the Roadster is ever recovered.

I haven't yet found anything that notes where the keys actually are, and in the images of the car's dashboard Starman's arm obscures the view of the ignition.

Where are Starman's keys? If they're not in the Roadster, will they be kept in case a recovery is ever launched?

Comment: I suspect that lithobraking will render them useless, but there's a slim chance that in a few decennia (centuries, millenia...) someone will have a pet project - or demonstration of their salvage business' capabilities - that will recover the Roadster.

Comment: Tesla uses a keyless entry and ignition system, the key could be anywhere in the car.

Comment: @GdD Thanks, that wasn't clear from the other question.

Comment: @GdD I agree the Model S, X, and 3 do use keyless systems.  The Roadster however was their first car based on the Lotus Elise, so that may not be correct.

Comment: They are hidden above the drivers side visor. No one would think of looking for them there

Comment: @Woody Thank you for the good laugh!  And it's certainly not a place a certain *narcissist* would think anyone else would look!